# Why doesn't num2fixpt function return my expected counterpart fixed point value?

Tags: matlab, fixed-point

I am trying to convert from float/double to fixed point notation,  for instance let's use the number `x = 0.39` as input.

I would like to convert x into its unsigned 16 bits fixed-point counterpart, to do so in C++ I am accustomed to use the expression `xFixedPoint = round(x*2^(16))`, this will make that the fixed point version of `0.39` is `25559`.

However, I cannot get that result if I make use of [`num2fixpt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/num2fixpt.html) function, I am using it in the following way

```
num2fixpt(0.39, ufix(16)) 
ans = 0
```

What am I doing wrong when using `num2fixpt` function?

Answer (score 0):

>> num2fixpt(0.39,ufix(16),2^-2)

ans =

0.2500

So you also need to scale to get the integer representation, i.e. 2^16*num2fixpt(...)

Comment: why are you setting the `2^-2` ?

Comment: Apolgies I don't sign in too often, so had missed your question.  It's because this third argument specifies the smallest representable value in the fixed point representation.  If you used 2^-3 your answer would be good to an eighth, so the value would be 0.375.